# How do I update exif DateTimeOriginal based on filename?

Tags: bash, perl, photo, exiftool

I want to share 10K photos using Google Photos.  These images were
scanned, so they don't have correct DateTimeOriginal for chronological ordering.

I need to update DateTimeOriginal to YYYY:01:01 00:00:00 to allow me to organize these within Google Photos for sharing
and having some sense of order.  My understanding is Google uses exif DateTimeOriginal for sorting.

My photo naming conventions:

1967 Smith G & J Wedding - 3.jpg

1962 Smith Family Reunion - 87.jpeg

1990 Smith 50th Anniversary - 16.jpeg

I tried this:

```
exiftool "-datetimeoriginal < ${filename;$_=substr($_,0,3)} 01:01 12:00:00" DIR
```

but receive a BASH "bad substitution error"

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: The shell will interpret `$` variables in a double quoted string. Try single quoting the code you pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close with your original, but as @Grinnz said, you need to use single quotes.  Additionally, you want the first 4 numbers for the year, but you're only grabbing 3.

So try:
`exiftool '-DateTimeOriginal<${filename;$_=substr($_,0,4)} 01:01 12:00:00' FileOrDir`

The startup time of exiftool is its biggest performance hit, so you'll find this is much faster than looping over each file (see [exiftool Common Mistake #3](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/mistakes.html#M3)).

This command creates backup files.  Add `-overwrite_original` to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add `-r` to recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: This is much faster than looping provided above.  10k images using loop took 10minutes.   exiftool  native took 1 minute for 10k images.  Thanks this is the best answer.  I appreciate Mark's answer too!

Answer (score 3):

There may be a better way, but this works:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.jpg; do
   year=$(grep -Eo "^\d+" <<< "$f")
   echo File: $f, setting year:$year
   exiftool "-datetimeoriginal=${year}01:01 12:00:00" "$f"
done
```

**Debug Output**

```
File: 2013 Family Reunion.jpg, setting year:2013
    1 image files updated
File: 2017 Some wedding.jpg, setting year:2017
    1 image files updated
```

Try it on a **COPY** of your files in a temporary directory!

Comment: Yes!  Works for me.  Thanks. I'm sure there may be a native way to do this using exiftool's expressions, but this did the trick.